# E-mail client to run python script

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec

Is there an e-mail client under Ubuntu dekstop with GUI, which will let me create a rule based on subject/body and run python script? Please don't recommend procmail as it doesn't have gui.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: The script is doing some long time fetching/processing from web. But I don't think it matters. What really matters is that I want to leave my ubuntu box open with this e-mail client while I don't have remote access to it and remotely run that script by sending e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KMail](http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/kmail/) supports running Python scripts (or any arbitrary command) based on [filters](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdepim/kmail/filters.html).  It even supports piping the message to programs, so your Python script can perform certain actions based on its contents.

[image: KMail Add Filter screen]

To install it, look for KMail in the Software Center or Synaptic or run:

```
sudo apt-get install kmail
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know if the command is long running script, then it can be executed independently on KMail, will not freeze it and closing KMail will not affect the script?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does block on it.  Breaking away from it is trival, though: just pretend it's a daemon.  There are [many modules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=daemon&submit=search) that do it for you, but [doing it yourself](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012-fork-a-daemon-process-on-unix/) is rather simple too.